# setRequestedOrientation doesn't lock the orientation

Tags: android

I am trying to lock an activity to landscape mode and have an overlying activity receive and use the orientation changes. The top activity is partly transparent so it is important that the bottom activity locks and is displayed correctly. I have tried to set it programatically with `setRequestedOrientation()` and in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

When I lock the orientation using the manifest the top activity also locks. When I add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` the top activity changes orientation but so does the bottom activity. Sometimes the bottom activity goes completely blank (transparent) after the orientation changes.

This is in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TopActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    </activity>
</application>
```

`MainActivity` is the bottom activity. How do I properly handle the orientation changes so that the single activities are locked the way I set them to?

Answer (score 3):

just add screenOrientation to the activity which you don't want to rotate on orientation change in the manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

All other activities will automatically rotate on orientation change.
No need to give screenOrientation for other activities.

Answer (score 0):

1) To disable orientation (i.e. to prevent Android from restarting your activity if the user flips the phone), then specify "configChanges" in your AndroidManifest (like you're already doing, apparently), and then simply don't respond to any changes:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

2) Alternatively, let's say you want to force your app to "landscape" mode. Instead of "configChanges", you can specify "screenOrientation"

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" ... >
```

3) Finally, if you *want* to handle the orientation change, you'll need to a) save state, then b) do whatever processing you need (including, perhaps, notify other activities):

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: that's what I am doing at the moment which is giving me the weird results described above

Comment: only using <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" ... > without configChanges makes the bottom activity go blank. when using "configChanges", even though I don't respond to them, the orientation changes